‘09 Honda Accord Not Starting after going into limp mode
Good afternoon! I have a 2009 Honda Accord EXL 3.5L V6. Earlier today while driving it down the highway, it sputtered and went into limp mode so I pulled over and turned it off. It threw no engine codes at this time. I managed to get it to turn over by mashing the gas pedal, but as soon as I let off the gas the rpms drop and it dies. Now it will not start at all.
I have since pulled the fuel pump assembly apart. The filter is clean and the pump is working. I disconnected a fuel line right before the fuel rail and watched in pump gasoline out. I have also inspected my fuel lines for leaks.
Then I took off the air intake from the throttle body to make sure it was opening properly. The throttle body opens correctly in accordance with how far the gas pedal is pushed.
Still the ECU is not giving me any trouble codes. I know that the engine is in time because my timing sensors are working and I know it would not try to start if it was out of time.
Tomorrow I will test the fuel injectors and rail and check the engine valves to make sure the are opening and closing properly. After that I would have to try changing all of the spark plugs and ignition coils, but it seems extremely unlikely that enough of them would go bad all at once to cause this.
If anyone else has any suggestions I would really appreciate it. :)

Many times a bad crankshaft position sensor will not throw a code. It would cause it to not start. If it's easy to replace try that. They usually aren't very costly. Might be worth a try before spending a lot of diagnostic time on it. If it went to limp mode there will be a code that can be read by a scanner.

Remove spark plugs and examine/smell them for fuel. Normally a failure to start will be either spark or fuel related. No fuel on plugs suggest either fuel pump or injector failure.  A spark test can be performed with plugs out, connected to ignition coil with plug bases grounded to the engine as someone turns the ignition key to START as you observe for spark. Failure to see/smell fuel on plugs and zero spark suggests a crank sensor or ecm failure. Did you check for blown fuses?

Update: The engine was throwing no codes originally. I replaced the fuel pump and got the car to start, but all three cylinders on the front side of my engine were misfiring. Pulled off the valve cover and found that a valve spring retainer for cylinder 6 had come off so the valve was not actuating properly. Idk why the other 2 cylinders were misfiring but I’m sending the head to a shop to have it reconditioned and all valves, springs and whatnot checked
